# Blinking yellow light on my Apple Time Capsule

Tags: time-capsule

What does a blinking yellow light on my 2TB Time Capsule indicate?  Seems as if my WiFi is still working.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Tesserax's Answer](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3860676) on the Apple Support Communities.

> ```
>       A persistent, flashing amber light indicates that any of the several potential conditions may require your attention:
> ```
>
> - The base station has not yet been configured because it is new, or    the reset switch has been set.
> - You have selected a security configuration that is not recommended.
> - One of several other conditions, such as a disconnected Ethernet cable or invalid IP address has been detected.
>        (ref: http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?artnum=305101)
>
>   If you run the AirPort Utility, it will show an amber circle on the summary >page next to the area(s) causing the
>
> problem. Click on this amber circle and it should provide an explanation.

Comment: Thank you Jake3231!.  I resolved the issue by doing the following: (ran the Airport Utility, updated the firmware.  Had to re-enter my Apple password for my Apple ID.  Problem solved.  Same procedure for my Airport Express.

Comment: Glad to hear that you were able to resolve the issue!